# How to backup all the updates

Tags: system-installation, 13.10, backup

Is there any way to create an updated iso of my installed ubuntu so that I don't need to update next time I have to have a fresh instal.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not changing architecture (32-bit to 64-bit or vice versa) you can just back up `/var/cache/apt/archives`, restore it to the new machine and run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

That'll get all the applications migrated so you don't have to *download* them but it won't install them for you.

Better yet, try this-

```
dpkg --get-selections > installed-programs.log
```

That will dump a list of your currently installed applications to a text file. You can then move the file to the new machine and do

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < installed-programs.log
```

then do

```
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

to install the packages.

Comment: Where is that log file created and how can i install all updates using that log file in new machine please help me.